# Enlaces de sitio publicado salen con ip local, redirigir IP a nombre de sitio público

Tags: php, wordpress, php5, debian, apache2

Acabo de montar mi servidor con *Wordpress (Debian 7.11, apache2 y php5)* y ya se encuentra publicado en *luisarizaga.ddns.net* (a través de *Noip* con su *DNS dinámico*).

El problema aparece una vez que se accede... El sitio se publica y se puede acceder sin problemas. Lo que pasa luego es que todos los enlaces apuntan a la *IP interna* del *servidor 192.168.0.151*

¿Existe una forma para hacer que el *Apache* escriba *luisarizaga.ddns.net* en vez de *192.168.0.151* en donde se encuentra el usuario?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no me equivoco el problema está en Wordpress y no en Apache, cambia la dirección URL del sitio en la configuración de Wordpress.

Comment: Tal como dice @AlbertoMéndez, esto tienes que hacerlo en el dashboard de Wordpress o directo en la base de datos. Por ahora sólo estás enmascarando la dirección oficial con que instalaste WP

Answer (score 0):

Había que editar en la configuración de *WordPress*. En *ajustes -> URL* y listo.